# In English, is there a difference between square and squared?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, education

For example, if I say "one over $x$ square/squared"

Do I mean: $1/\sqrt{x}$ or $1/x^2$?

Is there some other way to distinguish between the English pronounciation between $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: In English, we often say "square root of $x$" (or sometimes just "root $x$") for $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: It can only be *squared*, and it means $\frac1{x^2}$. $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is generally *one over the square root of* $x$, *one over square root* $x$, or *one over root* $x$

Comment: That's one more reason why maths has it's own language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would understand both "one over $x$ squared" and "one over the square of $x$" to mean $\dfrac1{x^2}$

To get $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ I would want the word *root* or something similar, as in "one over the square root of $x$" or perhaps slightly ambiguously "the square root  of one over $x$".  Saying "$x$ to the minus a half" would mean the same thing

When reading the statistical test based on $\chi^2$, I would call this "a chi-squared test" but would understand someone saying "a chi-square test" to mean the same thing

Comment: Over the reals $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$ so it's not so ambiguous.

Comment: @Javi though $\frac{\sqrt{1}}{x}$ would usually be different

Comment: I didn't thought of that alternative, probably because it's so trivial, the failure of natural language to be associavite.